# Selenium HTML Table.. retaining WebElements clicking away from page

Tags: c#, html, selenium, webdriver

I'm working in a standard HTML table (tr(rows), td(data))

For each record I have to click into the detail page for each row to determine whether or not it is a valid policy to continue test procedure.

When it is not valid the script clicks a back button on the page to return to the policy table. However, of course, because the browser navigated away from the table page the WebElements in the table have gone stale and can no longer be accessed.

I've attempted to store the webelements in a list like this ...

```
List<IWebElement> rows = new List<IWebElement>(table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr")));
```

... but this does not resolve the issue with the elements going stale.

Because each step returns back to the ...

```
foreach (var row in rows)
```

... line, which of course comes after storing the webelements, I have not found a way to first re-store the tr webelements before continuing.

Has anyone come across this or has anyone found a clever way to deal with this situation I haven't come across yet?

Answer (score 0):

When you back to the policy table page from policy detail page, you need to find the rows again on the policy table page.

```
List<IWebElement> rows = new List<IWebElement>
                         (table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr")));

foreach (var row in rows) {

   ...
   // click back button on detail page
   backButton.click()
   // find the rows on table page again
   sleep(<5-10 seconds>) for debug purpose,
   rows = new List<IWebElement>(table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr")));

}

// I'm not suer the foreach can remain the next iterate index even
// I assign new value to the `rows`.  If foreach can't work in such case,
// change to `for(var i=0;i<length;i++)` pattern.
```

Comment: I tried that after the 'back' click. I tried to refresh the 'rows' element by redoing the findelements line, but I still get the staleelementexception.

Comment: add some sleep before find rows again.

Comment: I suspected that might be happening too soon. I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

I do have similar kind of scenario, And I execute it by for loop.

You may refer this example (Syntax belongs to Java, You may refer it as according to C#)

```
public void locateElement(int i) {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@class=''])[" + i + "]")).click();
}

    try {
        List<WebElement> rows = new List<WebElement>(table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr")));

        for (int i = 1; i <= rows.size(); i++) {

            //To locate on main page, need to use i for each row
            locateElement(i);   

            rows = new List<IWebElement>(table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr")));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Won't this only work if the class attribute of the element is an integer? In this case each tr line only has one attribute, class, and each row alternates back and forth between class=odd and class=even.

Thinking about trying something similar to see if I can locate the specific row by using .ElementAt(i).

Comment: You can define specific row also. But I did not understand your requirements with ref to your comments.

Comment: I now see you're specifying the index in brackets. I didn't see that when I commented initially. I tried this but I wasn't able to get this to work. Got a 'nosuchelementexception'.

Comment: @HeadlyvonNoggin So you need to focus on your targeted element.Where you are locating, If its different page then you need to wait with Explicit wait or sleep

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to keep the elements list when you navigate to other URL because the DOM has been cleared so all references will be cleared.

You have to count the rows and loop through that number.

```
List<WebElement> rows = new List<WebElement>(table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr")));
var rowsCount = rows.Count;
for(int i=0; i<rowsCount; i++)
{
    var row = rows[i];
    // do what you need to do on this row e.g. row.Click();
    row.Click();

    // click back and wait 
    back.Click();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);

    rows = new List<WebElement>(table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr")));
}
```